# memory used by glassfish vs heap dump

Tags: jakarta-ee, memory, glassfish

I am trying to find memory leak in an application. It's a Java EE app running on GlassFish 2 with Hibernate and Lucene.

System monitor tells me that the memory used by GlassFish is more than 4gb. But when I open a heap dump in jprofiler I it tells me that there is only about 600mb allocated.

What do you think is wrong in what I am doing?

Do you think it is possible that the rest are objects that should be garbage collected and there is something wrong with gc? We process a lot of data so I am sure there are a lot of objects created in a short time.

Comment: You can use [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to see exactly how the memory is allocated (i.e. current heap size vs allocated heap size)

Comment: The problem occurs on production. I cant open ports for jmx and rmi. So I have to use tools installed on the server and with no X

Answer (score 0):

The `600MB` mentioned by `JProfiler` is java's heap which will get expanded as need up to max heap space.
The `4GB` mentioned by system monitor is the memory used by all application (JVM, your server etc)

Comment: No it is not. At the beginning it takes much less.

Comment: @piotrek:Not sure what you mean

Comment: I meant that when app starts it uses less memory. It is growing during the time.